# Not able output values properly read from another file in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash

I have a source file with the below information. I'm trying to output these variables from a bash script. But it is not showing proper results if i try to output two variables using single "echo" command. Why is this behaviour ?

source file:

```
fname=john
lname=wick
```

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/john/automation/sourcefile

echo "Name is ${fname} ${lname}"
```

Output:

```
wickis john
```

Comment: Most probably the `sourcefile` has Windows line endings AKA carriage returns. Try running `dos2unix /home/john/automation/sourcefile` before your script.

Comment: What you describe is impossible, you must be mistaken.